# Spring security authorize taglib with jstl variable if statement not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

I have a problem on my jsp where i am trying to hide some content based on a users spring security role but also on another variable (store) in my spring security user object. I can't get the syntax correct.

I have a property in my security object named store. When I try and print it out using the following...

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.store" var="userStore"/>
<c:out value="${userStore }"/>
<sec:authentication access="hasRole('ROLE_LEVEL_7')"/>                                                
   <div class="ym-fbox" id="store">
   <form:label path="store">Store<sup class="ym-required">*</sup></form:label>
   <form:input  path="store" class="required" />
</sec:authorize>
```

The user store variable gets printed correctly and no issues.

But then when I try and use this variable in conjunction with spring security taglibs to hide content my jso doesn't work properly...

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.store" var="userStore"/>
<c:if test="${userStore eq 'MyStore'}">
   <sec:authentication access="hasRole('ROLE_LEVEL_7')"/>                                     
      <div class="ym-fbox" id="store">
      <form:label path="store">Store<sup class="ym-required">*</sup></form:label>
      <form:input  path="store" class="required" />
   </sec:authorize>
```

I'm thinking what I am trying to do is not possible? Can anyone help me with a way to do this? The aim is to check the user store variable before checking the role. i.e. both variables are used to decide whether to hide content.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why the if statement did not work but I changed what I had to below and got it to work.

```
                    <sec:authentication property="principal.store" var="userStore"/>
                    <c:if test="${userStore eq lovStoreNone}">
                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_LEVEL_7')">
                    <div class="ym-fbox" id="store">
                        <form:label path="store"><spring:message code="label.store"/></form:label>
                        <form:select path="store">
                            <form:options items="${stores}" />
                        </form:select>  
                    </div>                                  
                    </sec:authorize>                                                                    
                    </c:if>
```